# Play Slick: How to write in memory unit test cases using Play and Slick

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, guice, slick

I am using Play 2.6 and Slick 3.2 with MySql database. But the problem is that I am not able to write test cases using h2 database. The problem is that, by using guice, I am not able to inject `DatabaseConfigProvider` in my repo. Following is my repo class implementation:

```
class CompanyRepoImpl @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                                (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends CompanyRepo {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass())
  private val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]

  import dbConfig._
  import profile.api._

  private val company = TableQuery[Companies]

------
}
```

My test case class:

```
class CompanyRepoSpec extends AsyncWordSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  private lazy val injector: Injector = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind(classOf[CompanyRepo]).to(classOf[CompanyRepoImpl]))
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .injector()
  private lazy val repo: CompanyRepo = injector.instanceOf[CompanyRepo]
  private lazy val dbApi = injector.instanceOf[DBApi]

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    Evolutions.applyEvolutions(database = dbApi.database("test"))
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(database = dbApi.database("test"))
  }

-----------------------
}
```

Testing application.test.conf

```
play.evolutions.db.test.enabled=true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true

slick.dbs.test.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.test.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.test.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL"
```

May be, my configuration are not valid for testing, so, how can we write test cases using scala, slick and play.

Comment: You can have a look at http://acolyte.eu.org/scala/